# How to XOR two hex values if one of them was a string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, xor

below is a snippet of the problem

```
string = "test"
for index, character in enumerate(string):
     value = hex(ord(character)) ^ 0xababab
```

This code is returning an error that it cannot XOR a string and an integer. So how can I get python to deal with the `hex(ord(character))` as an integer and not a string?

I tried casting it to an int by adding `int(hex(ord(character)))` but that returns an error of: Invalid literal for int with base10

Comment: You possibly meant this: `for ch in string: value = ord(ch) ^ 0xab`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `ord`, it's int.

```
for c in  s:
    print(ord(c) ^ 0xababab)
```

As you can see, these are equivalent:

```
1 == 0x01 # True
```